# Splash screen with Full screen activity not working as expected

Tags: android, fullscreen, splash-screen

I am using a Full-Screen activity in my app in android studio, and everything works fine, but when the splash screen is over (after 3000 ms), the main activity or home starts, but if I use the back button from the android phone, the display goes back to the splash screen and it stays on this splash screen (you can not go back to the main activity again)...

What code can I use to avoid this? (only show once the splash screen when the app is launched and never go back to it even if I press the back button).

Thanks in advance..

Comment: a simple `finish()` after starting new activity will suffice

Comment: Can you specify where? in which method? I tried adding this to several different methods and it did not work? Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I already figured out what you said. This works adding it after startActivity (intent)..But now if I use this code, another condition is created which I do not want. That condition is, if you now press the back button, it acts as the home button of the andorid device but I want to stay on the app no matter what. I already found how to correct this, but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. If you want to prevent the MainActivity from going back to the splash screen, you can use the next method in the Main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(false);
}
```

This method will also prevent the user from getting out of the app if they press the back button (so they stay on the app until they press the home button or the other button).

Comment: Just overriding `onBackPressed` and keeping it blank will also produce same result ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the back stack when you go from the splash screen activity by setting the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` & `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the intent.

So, in the splash screen activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class); // or MainActivity
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Can you specify where? in which method? I tried adding this to several different methods and it did not work? Thanks

Comment: You can look for any intent in the splash screen activity abd replace it with this intent.. But make sure that to change the target activity name